# JSON to CSV for Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I know there are many question to this but I am having trouble manipulating the data.

I have this list:

```
['2017-05-31,20:00:00,71.1,73,', '2017-05-31,20:05:00,71.1,72.7,', '2017-05-31,20:10:00,71.1,72.5,', '2017-05-31,20:15:00,71.1,72.4,']
```

I need to convert this JSON format to a CSV where the CSV looks like so.

[image]

Comment: If you have trouble with your code, why didn't you write a question that includes that code, and asks for help fixing it? Instead of writing a question that reads like: "please do my work for me"? Hint: read [mcve] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: So, what have you tried? Exactly what "trouble" did you have?

Comment: It looks like a list rather than JSON. Also what is the trouble? did you use the `csv` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
my_list = ['2017-05-31,20:00:00,71.1,73,', '2017-05-31,20:05:00,71.1,72.7,', '2017-05-31,20:10:00,71.1,72.5,', '2017-05-31,20:15:00,71.1,72.4,']
# create and open a file for writing
with open("my_file.csv", "w") as fout:
    # iterate through your list
    for element in my_list:
        # write your element in your file plus a \n to trigger a new line
        fout.write(element+"\n")
```

et voilà!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
result = []
for item in myList:
    row = item.split(',')
    result.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.to_csv("myFile.csv", index = False)
```